# react native ios crash on launch UIKitCore

Tags: react-native

we're getting a small number but regular crashes on launch in a production app.
We have Crashlytics and Sentry but i cant see any references to the react code.

Here is a couple of stacktraces

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x2d318 __abort_with_payload + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x2fc24 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 104
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x2fbbc abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 30
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x2d0b4 _objc_fatalv(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, char const*, char*) + 116
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x2d040 _objc_fatalv(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, char const*, char*) + 30
5  libobjc.A.dylib                0x5acc weak_register_no_lock + 392
6  libobjc.A.dylib                0xa924 objc_storeWeak + 448
7  UIKitCore                      0x2a2ee0 -[_UIBoundingPath initWithCoordinateSpace:] + 96
8  UIKitCore                      0x613fc4 -[_UIComplexBoundingPath initWithCoordinateSpace:orientation:scale:boundingPathBitmap:] + 112
9  UIKitCore                      0x3f11d0 -[_UIScreenComplexBoundingPathUtilities boundingPathForWindow:] + 2836
10 UIKitCore                      0x675ddc -[UIWindow _boundingPath] + 204
11 UIKitCore                      0x1b1650 -[UIView(UIViewBoundingPathSupportInternal) _effectiveBoundingPathAndBoundingPathView:] + 244
12 UIKitCore                      0x4bab4c -[UIView(UIViewBoundingPathSupport) _rectTuckedAgainstBoundingPathEdge:withSize:cornerRadii:minimumPadding:] + 260
13 UIKitCore                      0x6b74f8 -[_UISheetLayoutInfo _unsafeInsets] + 160
14 UIKitCore                      0x71f18 -[_UISheetLayoutInfo _marginsWhenFloating] + 184
15 UIKitCore                      0x3aca4c -[_UISheetLayoutInfo _isEdgeAttached] + 52
16 UIKitCore                      0x467ffc -[_UISheetLayoutInfo _reversedIndexOfLastUndimmedDetent] + 84
17 UIKitCore                      0x2d713c -[_UISheetLayoutInfo _activeDetentValues] + 348
18 UIKitCore                      0x24b990 -[_UISheetLayoutInfo _offsetForCurrentActiveDetent] + 48
19 UIKitCore                      0x583b5c -[_UISheetLayoutInfo _frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView] + 100
20 UIKitCore                      0x3cad98 -[UISheetPresentationController _containerViewLayoutSubviews] + 652
21 UIKitCore                      0x2231dc -[UITransitionView layoutSubviews] + 92
22 UIKitCore                      0x18c17c -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2592
23 QuartzCore                     0x407fc CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 532
24 QuartzCore                     0x32c60 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 136
25 QuartzCore                     0x475b4 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*) + 452
26 QuartzCore                     0x504a8 CA::Transaction::commit() + 704
27 QuartzCore                     0x323a0 CA::Transaction::flush_as_runloop_observer(bool) + 88
28 UIKitCore                      0x53e6e0 _UIApplicationFlushCATransaction + 72
29 UIKitCore                      0x7d8d5c _UIUpdateSequenceRun + 84
30 UIKitCore                      0xe5fedc schedulerStepScheduledMainSection + 144
31 UIKitCore                      0xe5f6a4 runloopSourceCallback + 92
32 CoreFoundation                 0xbb414 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
33 CoreFoundation                 0xcc1a0 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 208
34 CoreFoundation                 0x5694 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 268
35 CoreFoundation                 0xb05c __CFRunLoopRun + 828
36 CoreFoundation                 0x1ebc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
37 GraphicsServices               0x1374 GSEventRunModal + 164
38 UIKitCore                      0x514b58 -[UIApplication _run] + 1100
39 UIKitCore                      0x296090 UIApplicationMain + 364
40 App.                           0x72a4 main + 8 (main.m:8)
```

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x2d318 __abort_with_payload + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x2fc24 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 104
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x2fbbc abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 30
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x2d0b4 _objc_fatalv(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, char const*, char*) + 116
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x2d040 _objc_fatalv(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, char const*, char*) + 30
5  libobjc.A.dylib                0x5acc weak_register_no_lock + 392
6  libobjc.A.dylib                0xa924 objc_storeWeak + 448
7  UIKitCore                      0x2a2ee0 -[_UIBoundingPath initWithCoordinateSpace:] + 96
8  UIKitCore                      0x613fc4 -[_UIComplexBoundingPath initWithCoordinateSpace:orientation:scale:boundingPathBitmap:] + 112
9  UIKitCore                      0x3f11d0 -[_UIScreenComplexBoundingPathUtilities boundingPathForWindow:] + 2836
10 UIKitCore                      0x675ddc -[UIWindow _boundingPath] + 204
11 UIKitCore                      0x1b1650 -[UIView(UIViewBoundingPathSupportInternal) _effectiveBoundingPathAndBoundingPathView:] + 244
12 UIKitCore                      0x4bab4c -[UIView(UIViewBoundingPathSupport) _rectTuckedAgainstBoundingPathEdge:withSize:cornerRadii:minimumPadding:] + 260
13 UIKitCore                      0x6b74f8 -[_UISheetLayoutInfo _unsafeInsets] + 160
14 UIKitCore                      0x71f18 -[_UISheetLayoutInfo _marginsWhenFloating] + 184
15 UIKitCore                      0x3aca4c -[_UISheetLayoutInfo _isEdgeAttached] + 52
16 UIKitCore                      0x467ffc -[_UISheetLayoutInfo _reversedIndexOfLastUndimmedDetent] + 84
17 UIKitCore                      0x2d713c -[_UISheetLayoutInfo _activeDetentValues] + 348
18 UIKitCore                      0x24b990 -[_UISheetLayoutInfo _offsetForCurrentActiveDetent] + 48
19 UIKitCore                      0x583b5c -[_UISheetLayoutInfo _frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView] + 100
20 UIKitCore                      0x3cad98 -[UISheetPresentationController _containerViewLayoutSubviews] + 652
21 UIKitCore                      0x2231dc -[UITransitionView layoutSubviews] + 92
22 UIKitCore                      0x18c17c -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2592
23 QuartzCore                     0x407fc CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 532
24 QuartzCore                     0x32c60 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 136
25 QuartzCore                     0x475b4 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*) + 452
26 QuartzCore                     0x504a8 CA::Transaction::commit() + 704
27 QuartzCore                     0x323a0 CA::Transaction::flush_as_runloop_observer(bool) + 88
28 UIKitCore                      0x53e6e0 _UIApplicationFlushCATransaction + 72
29 UIKitCore                      0x7d8d5c _UIUpdateSequenceRun + 84
30 UIKitCore                      0xe5fedc schedulerStepScheduledMainSection + 144
31 UIKitCore                      0xe5f6a4 runloopSourceCallback + 92
32 CoreFoundation                 0xbb414 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
33 CoreFoundation                 0xcc1a0 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 208
34 CoreFoundation                 0x5694 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 268
35 CoreFoundation                 0xb05c __CFRunLoopRun + 828
36 CoreFoundation                 0x1ebc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
37 GraphicsServices               0x1374 GSEventRunModal + 164
38 UIKitCore                      0x514b58 -[UIApplication _run] + 1100
39 UIKitCore                      0x296090 UIApplicationMain + 364
40 App.                           0x77f8 main + 8 (main.m:8)
41 ???                            0x105a99da4 (Missing)
```

my only clue is from "initWithCoordinateSpace:orientation:scale:boundingPathBitmap" If there was a corrupt http image reference could this be causing a crash somewhere?

We are also using Firebase in-app-messaging. Could this be crashing the app on startup?

Comment: If you can't reproduce how do you know this crash is "on launch"?

Comment: @matt because we have Crashlytics and Sentry logs in production